# How do I use an existing type as the argument types of a function?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have a type:

```
type Book = {
  title: string
  pages: Page[]
}
```

and I want to have a function, say `readBook`, that takes the fields of `Book` as arguments, but doesn't take the `Book` itself (for historical reasons). How can I type this function correctly in a way that doesn't involve manually spreading into the arguments?

```
function readBook(title: string, pages: Page[]) { ... } // functional, but not ideal
function readBook(book: Book) { ... }  // also functional, but involves more work for my needs
function readBook(...args: Book) { ... } // does not work, `args` needs to be an array type
function readBook(...Book) { ... } // does not work, syntax error
```

I want to be able to do something that looks something like this:

```
function readBook(...Book) {
  console.log(title)
  pages.map(page => readPage(page))
}
```

Is there any way to do this, or something close?

Comment: An object (type) isn't semantically ordered, but positional arguments inherently are.

Comment: Destructure it? `function readBook({ title, page }: Book) {` Do note that the tooltip will say `arg_0: Book` or some other useless nonsense though...

Comment: this does not make sense to me: "a function [...] that takes the fields of Book as arguments, but doesn't take the Book itself"

Comment: @geoffrey a map type like `{ a: string, b: number } ` to `function foo(a: string, b: number)` the problem is the thing jonrsharpe pointed out: there's no way to make the conversion without specifying an ordering. JS objects retain insertion order but I don't think TS has any concept of entry ordering in a map type at the *type* level. OP is going to need to do the work to implement one of the first two options they propose.